# SonarQube error - Throwing a dedicated exception instead of generic exception for an Abstract class

Tags: java, exception

I am cleaning up SonarQube issues, and one of the errors complains: **Define and throw a dedicated exception instead of using a generic one.**

```
public abstract class Message {

    public abstract byte[] getPayload() throws Exception;

    public abstract Optional<String> getStringMessage() throws Exception;

}
```

Since this is a class from the library that people use as an API, and an abstract class that people inherit, I'm not sure if changing this to throw a dedicated exception would impact other services and thus, not okay. Any advice, direction, answer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Two things to consider : use and extension. For use, it won't be a problem because users probably already catch a generic exception (which is still horrible practice but anyway) so their catch clause will still work if you have a custom exception. However for people who extended your class, their implementation will be broken by the new code because the new signature won't match. Throwing a generic exception was a bad idea, but now you can't fix it without breaking something unfortunately

Comment: Thank you for the advice Arthur! I would probably just skip this error, but just curious, what does it mean by the new signature won't match?

Comment: Imagine a developer has your library in his code (a dependency). For some reasons he wanted to extend the `Message` class. So he overrides the `getPayload` and `getString` method (because he wants to). His code works fine. Now you release a new version of your code with a custom exception on those methods. If he simply upgrades his dependency, he will have a compilation error saying his overriden function doesn't match the original one (because now, it has to throw CustomException and not Exception). This is what we call a breaking change

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not** change the thrown `Exception` before having checked which `Exception`s are thrown by `Message`'s extending types. You might break existing code (see below).

If every extending type did not use a more specific `Exception`, then, you **have to** replace it with a clearer & more idiomatic one.

A custom `Exception` can carry additional data as class fields. This additional data can be set at throwing point (which is usually where that data is available only), and inspected at upper levels, when handled.

Being that this class acts as a sort-of `interface` (consider refactoring it to an `interface`, indeed), it will be the one exposed/used everywhere, and thus it needs to be as clear as possible.

A couple possible names might be

```
MessageException
PayloadRecoveryException
```

---

Applying a more specific `Exception`, having extending types which already provide specific ones, or even just the base `Exception`, will result in compile errors

Starting point

[image]

Now, upgrade the `Exception` to a "custom" one. **Error**!

[image]

So be careful, or you'll have people complaining.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at the usages of these methods. About refactoring it to an interface, will it also impact other teams? I assume as of now, people will extend the abstract class, but if I change it to interface, they have to implement it. I guess I have to let other teams know about this refactoring. Also, what is the reason you recommend interface instead of abstract class? Sorry, this might be too many questions, I want to learn :)

Comment: @louprogramming yes, it will impact every user of that definition. An interface is per-se just a class with all its methods marked as abstract. But, classes can implement multiple interfaces, while only one class can be extended. You're basically limiting your users on this aspect. An interface, also, **cannot carry data** alone, while an abstract class **might do**, and **cannot provide method implementations**, while an abstract class **might do**. Interfaces are also the de-facto standard when exposing APIs